# ¿Bulma.io incluye javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

He comenzado a utilizar Bulma.io como framework, sin embargo el handling que debería de hacerse con javascript no me aparece, alguien sabe como activarlo? O se agrega por separado? Gracias.

Comment: no, bulma no utiliza js. En la documentación puedes ver como linkean a ejemplos de js https://bulma.io/documentation/form/file/#javascript

Comment: Enhorabuena, yo uso también `Bulma`, precisamente por su sencillez, como dice en la [página de inicio](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/): *You **only need 1 CSS file** to use Bulma*. Nunca lo he usado con Javascript... Para el uso de `FontAwesome` sí indican que se debe agregar un archivo .js en el documento.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D